# Генерация случайных ссылок без повторений

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Я создаю своего бота для магазина в тг с pytelegrambotapi
Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать так что б при нажатии на кнопку бот выдавал рандомную ссылку и не повторялся. Буду очень благодарен если напишете от а до я

Comment: Без кода вряд ли мы что-то можем сделать. Рандом из чего? Есть список ссылок? Тогда воспользуйтесь функцией `random.choice()`.

Comment: например, удаляйте выбранный элемент.

Comment: Есть список ссылок, и я хочу что б при нажатии на кнопку бот выдавал одну из списка ссылок и больше по повторялся

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

urls = ['youtube.com', 'stackoverflow.com', 'google.com']
@bot.message_handler(
    func=lambda message: message.text.lower() == "ссылка")
    # метод choice просто выбирает любой элемент
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, random.choice(urls))  
    # без повторов
    if len(urls) != 0:
        i = random.randint(0, len(urls)-1) # возьмём рандомный индекс
        # отправляется рандомная ссылка по индексу i и удаляется
        # элемент по этому индексу из списка
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, urls.pop(i)) 
    
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "ссылок нет")
```

Предупреждаю, если вы не задействуете что-то вроде баз данных, то один пользователь сможет просмотреть все ссылки, а другой уже нет.

Comment: Подобное количество комментариев, по-моему, уже моветон. И так ясно. Лучше кратко охарактеризовать основные блоки кода, но не пересказывать их.